# How to test onCreateView() of Fragment and displaying data on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I request from server data using Retrofit2.0 in onViewCreated() of Fragment and received data display via RecyclerView 
want to know how to test via espresso

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecipePresenter.loadData("");
}
   private void updateContent(List<Recipe> recipes) {
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
    mRecipeAdapter.setRecipes(recipes);
}
```

I found samples that tests on button click , need to test onCreate() and received data display via RecyclerView

Comment: Do you mean that you want to test if recycler view get populated with data?

Comment: Yes, mainly how to test these 2 methods